# How to associate dictionary key and values when data comes from different places - Python 3.5 / bs4 / Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

(I am a newbie so maybe there is a better way to do this using other modules?)
I am trying to associate keys to values, but the data comes from two different inputs.

On my target wepage of job listings there is a job title, and a job description right below to each job. Both are text, but the job title also contains a link to the unique webpage with a longer description.

What I am trying to do is to download job title, associate it to job description (and later on add to that key/value record some kind of unique id, possibly based on the url of the job offer. Once I have that I would like to send all of these data points into an xls sheet for verification/duplicate removal and storage)
I checked other answers, but they were above my technical level, or not quite what I need. I guess I need to use a loop or function, but not sure what to write in it. Thanks for help!

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.infojobs.net/jobsearch/search-results/list.xhtml#f1=1&item_showFilters=false&item_showExtraFilters=false&f2=20&f3=&f4=0&f5=&f6=9&f7=&f8=0&f9=0&f10=0&f11=0&f12=&f13=true&f14=true&f15=10&f16=true&f17=&f18=&f19=0&f20=4&f21=3002&f22=0&f23=26931879312&f24=0&f25=&f26=0&f27=false&f28=&f29=1&f30=&f31=-2147483648&f32=-2147483648&f34=&item_vieneUrlExecutive=false")
text_offer_description = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('job-list-description')
text_offer_title = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('job-list-title')

dict = []

for el in text_offer_title:
    dict.append(el.text)
    print(el.text)

# If/else? Here I'll check if value already in dict or not 
# barcode = driver.current_url (will assign a "barcode" to that key-value pair)
# print(barcode)
driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you have *no association between titles and descriptions*. I would find all "job" blocks and for every block get the title and the description:

```
for offer in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("ul#offer-list > li[itemType$=JobPosting]"):
    text_offer_description = offer.find_element_by_css_selector('p.job-list-description').text
    text_offer_title = offer.find_element_by_css_selector('h2.job-list-title a').text

    print(text_offer_description, text_offer_title)
```

Comment: Thanks @Alecxe this is good, but I am trying to find a way to associate the two values and I am not sure how to finish what you are explaining here. How can I express programmatically "for this block of offer and description, keep them together and give them this unique ID" (so I can later operate on them and not act on those I already acted on before. E.g. If I have visited/stored this offer before, skip. If not, add to he dictionary with this new id and continue program"...